# subgroup definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$H \subseteq \text{group  } G $, $H$ is not empty.

If for any $a,b \in H$, we have $a^{-1}b^{-1} \in H$ , is it possible to deduce that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ ?

I feel like this is not necessarily true because the identity can't be proven to be in $H$, but I can't find an counterexample.

Comment: No because we don't know if the inverse of $a^-1b^-1$ is in H. And yes we can't show the identity is in there too.

Comment: But you need to prove it. You can't say "what you don't know" is false. What you said is my intuition, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Perhaps this is a typo because $ab^{-1}\in H$ works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Consider $\mathbb{Z}/3$.

Comment: What is the / here?

Comment: The set $\{0,1,2\}$ under addition mod 3.

Comment: {0,1,2} under addition mod 3? What's H and G respectively?

Comment: @user93383: Serkan's example is correct: the subset $H=\{1\}$ here and $G$ is the additive group $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. Also $H=\{2\}$ would work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In general a counterexample: take a finite group $G$ with $3 \vert|G|$. By Cauchy' Theorem we can pick an element $g \in G$ of order 3. Now take $H=\{g\}$.

The story goes a little further.

**Proposition** Let $H$ be a subset of a group $G$ such that $\forall a,b \in H:  a^{-1}b^{-1} \in H$. Then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if the identity element $e \in H$.

Proof. The only if part is obvious, so assume $e \in H$. We have to show that $H$ is closed under the group multiplication and that inverses lie in $H$. Let’s do the latter first: take $a \in H$, then by the property $a^{-1}e^{-1}= a^{-1} \in H$. Now take $ a,b \in H$, then $ b^{-1}a^{-1}=(ab) ^{-1} \in H$. But inverses lie in $H$, so $ab \in H \Box$.

We can in fact construct an infinite number of counterexamples.

Let $G$ be a group with $g \in G$ of order 6. Take $H=\{g,g^4\}$
Let $G$ be a group with $g \in G$ of order 9. Take $H=\{g,g^4,g^7\}$
Let $G$ be a group with $g \in G$ of order 12. Take $H=\{g,g^4,g^7,g^{10}\}$, and so on.

Comment: @Serkan, excellent infinite example!